# How to fix this error? E/RecyclerView: Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager set. Call setLayoutManager with a non-null

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an application chat for this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#8. I did everything seems to be correct, but it turns out this error: E/RecyclerView: Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager set. Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument. E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout.
How to fix this error? Help please.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
        // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
        finish();
        return;
    } else {
        mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
        if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }
    }

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
            .build();

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mMessageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    // New child entries
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> parser = new SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>() {
        @Override
        public FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
            if (friendlyMessage != null) {
                friendlyMessage.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }
            return friendlyMessage;
        }
    };

    DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD);
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendlyMessage> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendlyMessage>()
                    .setQuery(messagesRef, parser)
                    .build();
    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            return new MessageViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_message, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                        int position,
                                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            if (friendlyMessage.getText() != null) {
                viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
                viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            } else if (friendlyMessage.getImageUrl() != null) {
                String imageUrl = friendlyMessage.getImageUrl();
                if (imageUrl.startsWith("gs://")) {
                    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                            .getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(
                            new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                                        Glide.with(viewHolder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                                .load(downloadUrl)
                                                .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "Getting download url was not successful.",
                                                task.getException());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    Glide.with(viewHolder.messageImageView.getContext())
                            .load(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl())
                            .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                }
                viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            }


            viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Loand.this,
                        R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
            } else {
                Glide.with(Loand.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
            }

        }
    };

    mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition =
                    mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
            // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
            // of the list to show the newly added message.
            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                            lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });

    mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);

    // Initialize and request AdMob ad.
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Initialize Firebase Measurement.
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    // Initialize Firebase Remote Config.
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

    // Define Firebase Remote Config Settings.
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings firebaseRemoteConfigSettings =
            new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                    .setDeveloperModeEnabled(true)
                    .build();

    // Define default config values. Defaults are used when fetched config values are not
    // available. Eg: if an error occurred fetching values from the server.
    Map<String, Object> defaultConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
    defaultConfigMap.put("friendly_msg_length", 10L);

    // Apply config settings and default values.
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(firebaseRemoteConfigSettings);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultConfigMap);

    // Fetch remote config.
    fetchConfig();

    mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(mSharedPreferences
            .getInt(CodelabPreferences.FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH, DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT))});
    mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });

    mAddMessageImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addMessageImageView);
    mAddMessageImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new
                    FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                    mUsername,
                    mPhotoUrl,
                    null /* no image */);
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)
                    .push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private Action getMessageViewAction(FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {
    return new Action.Builder(Action.Builder.VIEW_ACTION)
            .setObject(friendlyMessage.getName(), MESSAGE_URL.concat(friendlyMessage.getId()))
            .setMetadata(new Action.Metadata.Builder().setUpload(false))
            .build();
}

private Indexable getMessageIndexable(FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {
    PersonBuilder sender = Indexables.personBuilder()
            .setIsSelf(mUsername.equals(friendlyMessage.getName()))
            .setName(friendlyMessage.getName())
            .setUrl(MESSAGE_URL.concat(friendlyMessage.getId() + "/sender"));

    PersonBuilder recipient = Indexables.personBuilder()
            .setName(mUsername)
            .setUrl(MESSAGE_URL.concat(friendlyMessage.getId() + "/recipient"));

    Indexable messageToIndex = Indexables.messageBuilder()
            .setName(friendlyMessage.getText())
            .setUrl(MESSAGE_URL.concat(friendlyMessage.getId()))
            .setSender(sender)
            .setRecipient(recipient)
            .build();

    return messageToIndex;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
}

        @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sign_out_menu:
            mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
            mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void causeCrash() {
    throw new NullPointerException("Fake null pointer exception");
}

private void sendInvitation() {
    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
            .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}

// Fetch the config to determine the allowed length of messages.
public void fetchConfig() {
    long cacheExpiration = 3600; // 1 hour in seconds
    // If developer mode is enabled reduce cacheExpiration to 0 so that each fetch goes to the
    // server. This should not be used in release builds.
    if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
        cacheExpiration = 0;
    }
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    // Make the fetched config available via FirebaseRemoteConfig get<type> calls.
                    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                    applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // There has been an error fetching the config
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error fetching config", e);
                    applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.d(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());

                FriendlyMessage tempMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                        LOADING_IMAGE_URL);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push()
                        .setValue(tempMessage, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                                                   DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                if (databaseError == null) {
                                    String key = databaseReference.getKey();
                                    StorageReference storageReference =
                                            FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                                    .getReference(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                                                    .child(key)
                                                    .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

                                    putImageInStorage(storageReference, uri, key);
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write message to database.",
                                            databaseError.toException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}

private void putImageInStorage(StorageReference storageReference, Uri uri, final String key) {
    storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(Loand.this,
            new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage =
                                new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                                        task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                                                .toString());
                        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).child(key)
                                .setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Image upload task was not successful.",
                                task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Apply retrieved length limit to edit text field. This result may be fresh from the server or it may be from
 * cached values.
 */
private void applyRetrievedLengthLimit() {
    Long friendly_msg_length = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong("friendly_msg_length");
    mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(friendly_msg_length.intValue())});
    Log.d(TAG, "FML is: " + friendly_msg_length);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

you should set layout manager to your recyclerview.

so you have to add below line

`mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);`